# Can AngularJS 4 run on IE9?

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

I am writing a small app to target some older browsers but I’d love to write it in Angular 4. Is it possible? Which polyfils do I need?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do..?

Comment: check angular.io > Docs > Advanced > Browser Support

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html and scroll down to "Mandatory polyfills".

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it will work in IE9

I recommend using the [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).
Assuming that you already have node and npm installed, to use the angular-cli run:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new PROJECT_NAME
```

That should be all you need, but if you need further help on this run `ng help`

This gets you a generic Angular 4.0 setup based on Webpack.  To support IE9, you will need to do two additional things.

1. Edit src/polyfills.ts.  Uncomment all of the imports under the IE9 comment. That section should look like this afterwards:

   ```
   /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
   import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
   import 'core-js/es6/object';
   import 'core-js/es7/object';
   import 'core-js/es6/function';
   import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
   import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
   import 'core-js/es6/number';
   import 'core-js/es6/math';
   import 'core-js/es6/string';
   import 'core-js/es6/date';
   import 'core-js/es6/array';
   import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
   import 'core-js/es6/map';
   import 'core-js/es6/set';
   import 'core-js/es7/array';
   ```
2. In tsconfig, edit the "target" field to be `"es5"`.  Your file should look something like this afterwards

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```